# Delphi 2007 - Is there a THeaderControl that works in the vertical direction

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, resizable, tgridpanel

I have a need to resize rows on a `TGridPanel`, and figured I could do it by having a `THeaderControl` left-aligned and resizing the TGridPanel rows when the `OnSectionResize` fires to match the section widths in the header control.

Unlike scrollbars however, the THeaderControl doesn't have a `Kind` property that determines whether its a horizontal or vertical-acting control.  Is there something that will give me this functionality?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no standard VCL control that will do this; you'd have to find a third party control (if there is one). Did you try searching the usual Delphi component sites? (I know you're aware that you can't ask about finding one here.)

Comment: Nothing I could see on Torry's/JVCL or Google search.  I may have to ditch the TGridPanel and do something with top-aligned panels and splitters.